# Why cant we initialise an array with the help of other array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i,j;
    int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int b[3][3]=a[3][3];

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        printf("%d",b[i][j]);
}

// Why can't we initialize array like this
```

Why can't I initialize the array with the help of array
here why I can't initialize the array with the help of array

Comment: Please do not post code as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Because ***assignment*** is not ***initialization*** and an array is NOT an ***lvalue***. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Answer (score 2):

You can, just not with the syntax you are using.  Here are a few options:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int
main(void)
{
        int i,j;
        int a[3][3] = {
                {1, 2, 3},
                {4, 5, 6},
                {7, 8, 9}
        };
        int *b[3] = { a[0], a[1], a[2] };
        int c[3][3];
        int (*d)[3] = a;
        memcpy(c, a, sizeof a);
        for( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
                for( j = 0; j < 3; j++ ){
                        printf("%d  %d  %d\n", b[i][j], c[i][j], d[i][j]);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare `int a[3][3]`. Then try to initialize `int b[3][3] = a[3][3];` but `a[3][3]` is out of bounds on the right hand side.   If you mean the single element `a[2][2]`, then can do `{ [0] = a[2][2] }` if that is what you want. c17, as far as I can tell, does not support array initialization from another array, i.e. use memcpy.

Answer (score 0):

In C, initializing or assigning a multidimensional array like that will throw invalid initializer as you wanted to initialize b with a.

```
int a[3][3]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int b[3][3];
memcpy (b, a, 3*3*sizeof(int));
```

C is not a high level language. It doesn't copy strings / multidimensional arrays when you're assigning. In C, assignment operator will always have complexity O(1). What you can do is working with the memory addresses.